# elisp , passing functions as arguments and call it, an Eval error happend, why?

Tags: emacs, elisp

my elisp program is:

```
(defun test (f x) (f x))
(test (lambda (x) (* x x)) 10)
```

run it, an error happened:

*** Eval error ***  Symbol's function definition is void: f

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Emacs is a lisp-2, so has a different namespace for functions and variables. So, in test, the f in the second (f x) is not the same as the (f) in the parameter list.

Try

```
(defun test (f x) (funcall f x))
```

All is good.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correction:

```
(defun test (f x)
  (funcall f x))

(test (lambda (x) (* x x)) 10)
```